# How do you use nestedText with python?

Tags: python-3.x

With https://pypi.org/project/nestedtext/

```
import nestedtext as nt

    def nestedText(self, reading=True, path="reviews.nt"):
        if reading == True:
            return nt.load(path)
        elif reading != True:
            nt.dump(reading, path)
            return self.nestedText(path=path)
```

This code runs into errors following this journey:

```
    return self.nestedText(path=path)
>    return nt.load(self.fil[path])
>    loader = NestedTextLoader(fp, top, source, on_dup, keymap, normalize_key)
>    report('content must start with key or brace ({{).', lines.get_next())
>    raise NestedTextError(template=message, *args, **kwargs)
>    File "<string>", line 0 nestedtext.nestedtext.NestedTextError
```

The file starts off as only touched, so size 0. And then I run nestedText([]). Assume the path works, even if I put it incorrectly here. It is correct on my code that is not edited with names as such.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass in `[]` as your only argument.  Thus `reading` gets [] which it interprets as false, so you use nt.dump() to write [] to reviews.nt.  Then nestedText reads reviews.nt using nt.load(path).  Notice that the `top` argument of nt.load() is not specified.  It defaults to dict, meaning that the top level of your nestedtext file is expected to be a dictionary.  The top level of your nestedtext file is a list, thus nt.load() raises a nt.NestedTextError.  You can fix this by passing `top=any` to nt.load().

I recommend that you always wrap nt.load() in a try-except block and catch nt.NestedTextError.